# How to make an image stop/start following cursor on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still very new to jquery and was wondering if anyone could help me with this.  I have a small script that detects the position of the cursor and has an image follow it.   I am stuck as to how I can get the image to stop/start following if the mouse button is clicked.   Could anyone help point me in the write direction?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Follow</title>
<link href="stylesheets/standard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("html").mousemove(function (e) {
var xPos = e.pageX;
var yPos = e.pageY;
$("#foxlocation").html("The fox is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);
$("#imgFollow").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});
});
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h2 id="foxlocation"></h2>
<img id="imgFollow" width="75px" height="75px" src="images/fox.jpg"></img>
<footer>Test2</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var init = true;
    $(document).on('click', function () {
        $(this)[init ? 'on' : 'off']('mousemove', follow);
        init = !init;
    });

    function follow(e) {
        var xPos = e.pageX;
        var yPos = e.pageY;
        $("#foxlocation").html("The fox is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);
        $("#imgFollow").offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FAfU/)

**EDIT:**

To start of with the function initialized, the easiest would be to just trigger a click:

```
    $(document).on('click', function () {
        $(this)[init ? 'on' : 'off']('mousemove', follow);
        init = !init;
    }).trigger('click');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FAfU/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  It works great, and I should have though of that, but is there anyway it can load the page with the image already following, then the user would have to click to make it stop and click again to make it start, instead of them having to load, then click twice to start following?

Comment: Or at least click once in the beginning to make it start instead of twice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example : <kbd>**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/31/)**</kbd>

With my solution, the image is following the mouse directly after the page loading without user interaction

I am using the CSS property

```
#imgFollow{
    position:absolute;
}
```

And your code except `.css()` instead of `.offset()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).mousemove(function (e) {
        var xPos = e.pageX;
        var yPos = e.pageY;
        $("#foxlocation").html("The fox is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);
        $("#imgFollow").css({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html").mousemove(function (e) {
        follow(e);
    })
    .click( function () {
        var foo = $.data( this, 'events' ).mousemove;
        if(typeof foo = 'function') {
          $(this).off('mousemove');
        } else {
          $(this).mousemove( function (e) {
            follow(e);
          });
        }
    });
});

function follow(e){
  var xPos = e.pageX;
  var yPos = e.pageY;
  $("#foxlocation").html("The fox is at: " + xPos + ", " + yPos);
  $("#imgFollow").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});
}
```

Comment: Oh bummer, adeneo beat me to it.